# Ajax post gives 403, csrf,node&express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, csrf

So previously I managed to pass the csrf token through a form, a log in form. But fail to pass the csrf token when trying to change pages through clicking on a certain element, p.

App.js

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
//bunch of requires

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var profile = require('./routes/profile');
var statistics = require('./routes/statistics');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));

//Security shyts

app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter({ setOnOldIE: true }));
app.use(helmet.frameguard('deny'));
app.use(helmet.hsts({maxAge: 7776000000, includeSubdomains: true}));
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(helmet.noCache());

// rest of USE
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'anystringoftext', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true}));
app.use(csrf()); // Security, has to be after cookie and session.
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// csrfToken usage
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/profile', profile);
app.use('/statistics', statistics);

//Error handlers

module.exports = app;
```

profileSite.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /*Hide elements*/
     .
     .

    /*Insert elements via effects*/
     .
     .


// The problem
    $('#statistics').click(function () {
        $.post('statistics');
    });



    /*Fade out elements*/
    $('.selection').click(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(500);
    });
    $('.settings').click(function() {
        $('.layer').fadeToggle();
    });
    $('.exit').click(function(){
        $('.layer').fadeToggle();
    });
    $('.save').click(function(){
        $('.layer').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

profile.ejs

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="<%= csrfToken %>">
//A bunch of html tags
```

I've also tried to use input but to no avail.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
```

Profile.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connectDB = require('../public/javascripts/connectDB.js');

/* GET profile page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//A bunch of queries and stuff
});

router.post('/statistics',function(req,res,next){
    console.log('it passed!');
    res.redirect('statistics);
});

module.exports = router;
```

statistics.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET statistics listing. */
router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('statistics',{title:'stats?');
});
```

module.exports = router;

I apologize if there is alot of excess code inserted in the question. Also this is the error I get after clicking on the p element.

On IntelliJ:

```
POST /statistics 403 1.476 ms - 887
```

And from the browser console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/statistics 403 
(Forbidden)n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ 
jquery.js:8630n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8166n.each.n.(anonymous function) @ 
jquery.js:8311(anonymous function) @ profileSite.js:28n.event.dispatch @ 
jquery.js:4435n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4121
```

So what i've tried is to pass the csrf token through data in $.post('statistics',{data:inputData}) is to have data = _csrf,token.. and inputData as csrfToken,req.csrfToken,body.csrfToken..

Answer (score 0):

It was actually rather simple:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content')}
    });
```

In the profileSite.js file.